# MariaDB Server crashes when performing mysqlcheck

Tags: mysql, mariadb, corruption

I'm checking my databases and I'm using this command :

```
mysqlcheck --all-databases -c -uroot -pxxxxxxx
```

But I'm getting this error :

> mysqlcheck: Got error: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during
> query when executing 'CHECK TABLE ... '

Error log shows that there's a corrupted index tree

> 2022-07-14 17:00:18 20 [ERROR] InnoDB: Corruption of an index tree:
> table `vod_ci_db`.`user_notifications` index
> `idx_notif_user_video_id`, father ptr page no 233557, child page no
> 1374780 2022-07-14 19:27:46 7 [ERROR] InnoDB: In pages [page id:
> space=11889, page number=1828917] and [page id: space=11889, page
> number=1374780] of index `idx_notif_user_video_id` of table
> `vod_ci_db`.`user_notifications`

But why does it crashes when finding a corrupted index? shouldn't it continue through all tables and gives me a summary after?

Best Regards,

Comment: What is result of SELECT @@version;  Someone may be able to assist.

Comment: Hi Wilson! 10.5.9-MariaDB

Comment: You may have already reviewed the complete content of this URL -  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqlcheck/   
 
Please view profile for contact info and get in touch if additional assistance is needed. (by Skype preferrably)  My Skype ID is  wlhauck@aol.com

Comment: Please also be acquainted with this URL that has more in-depth details on resolving a corrupted table.  

    https://ittutorial.org/best-ways-to-repair-corrupt-innodb-table-in-mysql/